# Easiest way to make QuickLook generator on OS X? (script -> html -> webkit view?)

Tags: objective-c, quicklook

I don't know Objective C but would very much like to make a simple QuickLook generator.

Here's my plan:

myfile.extension -> QuickLook generator parses the file using a script (e.g. a simple shell script or otherwise that I provide) that then outputs a html file -> QuickLook shows this html file using a webkit view

I'm basically looking for a template or a tutorial where I could just insert my own script into it and not worry about how the QuickLook generator itself works and without having to learn Objective C (which I am in the process of doing but slowly!).

Many thanks if anyone can help with this, or even just point me in the right direction. I'm sure it'll be of use to someone else in the future too.

Edit:

I have found the following, which I'd missed before, which does answer my question in part:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLDynamicGeneration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH15-SW2

This is a more complicated solution that I had hoped, and means I will have to delve into Objective-C. If anyone knows how I can simplify this code I would very much appreciate it.

e.g. is there a way of changing the line in the tutorial:

occasion=InitializeCoreDataStackWIthURL(url);

to something similar, like:

(String) occasion = (the output of myshellscript.sh $url)

Please bear in mind that I don't know Objective-C, so I have no idea how to write a core data stack or even what that is!

Many thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do Objective-C to write a generator but you will surely need to write C code.

Calling an external script (or whatever external code) in a generator is forbidden by Quick Look's sandbox.